# How to install xfce goodies in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, xfce

After installing xfce to replace default Gnome, I now want to install the `xfce-goodies` package. I have tried:

```
dnf install xfce4-goodies
```

and

```
yum install xfce4-goodies
```

without success. How can I do this?

Comment: It doesn't look like Fedora has a `xfce4-goodies` package in their repositories. https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/packages/?motif=xfce4%2A. You probably need to install each application included in the package individually.

Answer (score 3):

The package is only available as separate packages. For example, from the [debian](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xfce/xfce4-goodies) contents we can see one goodie is `xfce4-mailwatch-plugin`. A search with

```
sudo dnf search xfce4-mailwatch-plugin
```

will find that package.
For a more general search just use

```
sudo dnf search xfce
```

or use glob patterns like `'*xfce*mail*'`. You don't need `sudo` to search but it stops it building a separate cache for you and another for root.

Comment: tnx for answer. So I need to install each package seperately like `sudo dnf install xfce4-mailwatch-plugin` ?

Comment: I was thinking to use patterns and install all xfce4 related packages with `sudo dnf install xfce4-*` However seems there are so many unrelated dependencies going to be installed (140 packages, 204 MB).

Comment: I agree this is enormous. You can see why a goodies package would be useful.  You can get rid of some of the bigger packages from your list by excluding them. Add to your command `-x '*devel*' -x '*-dev-*' -x '*vala*'` to start with to reduce the size, then exclude similarly any other big packages until it seems reasonable. Or simply copy the list to install from the debian link, assuming the names match in fedora!